# Telephony Manager getCi() for LTE help needed

Tags: android

I am very new to Android coding and have been having lots of fun till now. I am stuck with an issue using the telephony manager, specifically for LTE. My getCi() method returns a value, which is correct, but not in the format in which I need it to be. For example, the value returned is 25605. What code can I use to take this number and create the correct Node B ID and Cell ID value which is what I want my app to display?

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);


    List<CellInfo> cellInfos = tm.getAllCellInfo();

    for(CellInfo cellInfo : cellInfos)
    {
        //CellInfoWcdma cellInfoWcdma = (CellInfoWcdma) cellInfo;
        CellInfoLte cellInfoLte = (CellInfoLte)cellInfo;
        //CellInfoGsm cellInfoGsm = (CellInfoGsm)cellInfo;

        //CellIdentityWcdma cellIdentityWcdma = cellInfoWcdma.getCellIdentity();
        //CellSignalStrengthWcdma cellSignalStrengthWcdma = cellInfoWcdma.getCellSignalStrength();
        CellIdentityLte cellIdentityLte = cellInfoLte.getCellIdentity();
        CellSignalStrengthLte cellSignalStrengthLte = cellInfoLte.getCellSignalStrength();

        netId = cellIdentityLte.getCi();
        netId2 = cellSignalStrengthLte.getLevel();
        //netId = cellIdentityWcdma.getCid() & 0xffff;
        //netId2 = cellSignalStrengthWcdma.getAsuLevel();
        //netId3 = netId2*2 -113;
```

nter code here

Comment: What have you tried so far on your own? We will not write code for you, but we love to see yours and help. FYI, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also may this be helpful to detect network status: https://gist.github.com/emil2k/5130324 ?

Comment: I have written the below. As you can see, I have commented out teh GSm and WCDMA portions in order to test the LTE part. The other technologies have worked and am able to get the information correctly. It is just with LTE that I am struggling with: CellIdentityLte cellIdentityLte = cellInfoLte.getCellIdentity();
            CellSignalStrengthLte cellSignalStrengthLte = cellInfoLte.getCellSignalStrength();

            netId = cellIdentityLte.getCi();
            netId2 = cellSignalStrengthLte.getLevel();

Comment: @Avi909gp I am trying to find out the same. If I have the output of cellIdentityLte.getCi() how to convert it to eNodeB id and cell ID or physical cell ID. Have you already found the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The value of cellIdentityLte.getCi() you have to convert to HEX.

Then the last two symbols you convert to DEC and this is the Local Cell ID.

The rest (except the last two symbols) you convert to DEC and this is the eNodeB.

I don't know Java, but here it is with Excel formulas. I think you'll get the logic

```
eNodeB =HEX2DEC(LEFT(DEC2HEX(E2),LEN(DEC2HEX(E2))-2)) 
Local_Cell_ID =HEX2DEC(RIGHT(DEC2HEX(E2),2))
```

where E2 is the output of cellIdentityLte.getCi()

I have tested this and checked the cell configuration. The values are the same.